# munin df plugin configuration

Tags: munin, lvm

Every time LVM snapshot is dropped, I receive Munin warnings:

```
Disk latency per device :: Average latency for /dev/vg/lv_mysql_snapshot
UNKNOWNs: Read IO Wait time is unknown, Write IO Wait time is unknown.

Disk latency per device :: Average latency for /dev/mapper/vg-lv_mysql-real
UNKNOWNs: Read IO Wait time is unknown, Write IO Wait time is unknown.

Disk latency per device :: Average latency for /dev/mapper/vg-lv_mysql_snapshot-cow
UNKNOWNs: Read IO Wait time is unknown, Write IO Wait time is unknown.
```

Is it any way to ignore the LVM partition notifications in munin? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your case a quick:

```
  [diskstats]
    env.exclude lv
```

should be enough. This should go in /etc/munin/munin.conf below the configuration of this host.